# How to set image file to ImageView or NetworkImageView using Volley in Android?

Tags: android

I have one API,it will give an image as response.Can you suggest me how can set that image to  ImageView.Thanks,
`

```
private static final String URL = "http://someapi";
setting images from api
person.setThumbnailUrl(Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load((File) items.get("profileImageLargeUrl")));
```

Comment: Your question is not clear .

Comment: Make your question clear

Answer (score 0):

This is the way you can set a picture from URL ussing Picasso (you don't need Volley):

```
ImageView picture = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image);

String urlImage = "https://...";
...

Picasso.with(this)
                .load(urlImage)
                .into(picture);
```

Also you can set other options, like spiner, fit, or errorImage:

```
.placeholder( R.drawable.progress_animation )
.error(R.drawable.error_image)
.fit()
```